# List as instance attribute stays empty despite object's definition has list contents

Tags: python-3.x, list, instance

I have class Level:

```
class Level:
    def __init__(self, level_name, level_stage, level_clear, monster, items, text):
        self.level_name = level_name
        self.level_stage = level_stage
        self.level_clear = level_clear
        self.monster = monster
        self.items = items
        self.text = []
```

where the instance attribute **text** is an empty list. Then I have my global objects:

```
level1 = Level(1, 1, False, monster1, sword2, [text11, text12])

text11 = "You enter a dark dungeon, and SUDDENLY"
text12 = "That was well done"
```

I also have similar lists in my Inventory class, to which I append/remove items from instance methods. In this case, I am trying to fill the list by defining the object, but this is not the correct way as I understand it because the list stays empty:

```
import classes as c #just for clarification of the c
print(len(c.level1.text))
print(c.level1.text)
```

returns

```
0
[]
```

My question is if there is a correct way to do this, I have not been able to find a solution scraping the web. Of course I could use a method to append the correct list items to each instance's list, but I wonder if there are more elegant solutions to this?

Comment: Why `self.text = []` and not `self.text = text` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you find yourself going `text1 =`, `text2 =`, `text3 = ` then it's time for a list `texts = []`. Same with `level1`, `level2`... just `levels = []`. Also, please show a [mcve] showing the actual classes instead of using English to describe "this is in class C". Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and the welcome. I chose self.text = [] because each level has several different text lines, which I intend to print using list indices (text[0] then text[1] and lastly text[2]). ggorlen I had the texts as strings in the object definition initially, and tried this to no prevail. Now that you say it I should make a dictionary and just point to it from the instances... :) Ok! I will remember that in the future.